# How to until wait 2 parallel retrofit calls both finish?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, viewmodel

I want to call 2 retrofit services in parallel and then do an action only when both of them finished, but I don't seem to figuer it out how.

I have a viewModel where I have defined my services:

```
var config= List<Configuration>
fun getClientProducts() {
    getClientClientConfigUseCase
        .build(this)
        .executeWithError({ config ->
             config = config
        }, {
           
        })
}

var therapies = List<DtoTherapy>
fun getTherapies() {
    getTherapiesUseCase
        .build(this)
        .executeWithError({ config ->
             therapies = it
        }, {
            
        })
}
```

And then I want to call both services in parallel in my fragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
   
    setupUi(view)
    loadUserData()

    viewModel.getClientProducts()
    viewModel.getTherapies()
}
```

And when both variables config and therapies have the value do an action. But as I said maybe one service take 1 sec to respond and another 4 secs, and I want only to perfom an action when both have finished. Any help with be appreciated.

Here is the class I use to build the use case call:

```
abstract class SingleUseCase<T> : UseCase() {
    private lateinit var single: Single<T>
    private lateinit var useCaseInterface: UseCaseInterface
    private var withLoader: Boolean = false
    private var withErrorMessage: Boolean = false

    internal abstract fun buildUseCaseSingle(): Single<T>

    fun build(useCaseInterface: UseCaseInterface): SingleUseCase<T> {
        this.withLoader = false
        this.withErrorMessage = false

        this.useCaseInterface = useCaseInterface
        this.single = buildUseCaseSingle()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doAfterSuccess { useCaseInterface.onSuccess(it) }
        return this
    }

    fun withLoader(): SingleUseCase<T> {
        this.withLoader = true
        return this
    }

    fun withErrorMessage(): SingleUseCase<T> {
        this.withErrorMessage = true
        return this
    }

    fun single(): Single<T> {
        return this.single
    }

    fun execute(onSuccess: ((t: T) -> Unit)) {
        useCaseInterface.onPrepareRequest(withLoader)
        buildObservable(onSuccess)
    }

    private fun buildObservable(onSuccess: ((t: T) -> Unit)) {
        disposeLast()
        lastDisposable = single
            .doFinally { useCaseInterface.onFinishRequest(this.withLoader) }
            .subscribe(
                { onSuccess(it) },
                {
                    useCaseInterface.onError(mapError(it), withErrorMessage)
                })

        lastDisposable?.let {
            compositeDisposable.add(it)
        }
    }

    fun executeWithError(onSuccess: ((success: T) -> Unit), onError: ((error: ApiError ) -> Unit)) {
        useCaseInterface.onPrepareRequest(withLoader)
        buildObservable(onSuccess, onError)
    }

    private fun buildObservable(onSuccess: ((success: T) -> Unit), onError: ((error: ApiError ) -> Unit)) {
        disposeLast()
        lastDisposable = single
            .doFinally { useCaseInterface.onFinishRequest(this.withLoader) }
            .subscribe(
                { onSuccess(it) },
                {
                    onError(mapError(it))
                    useCaseInterface.onError(mapError(it), withErrorMessage)
                })

        lastDisposable?.let {
            compositeDisposable.add(it)
        }
    }

    private fun mapError(t: Throwable): ApiError {
        return if(t is HttpException) {
            val apiError = t.response()?.errorBody()?.string()
            try {
                ApiError (t.code(), t.response()?.errorBody()?.string(), Gson().fromJson(apiError, GenericError::class.java))
            } catch(e: Exception) {
                ApiError (-2, "Unkown error")
            }
        } else ApiError (-1, "Unkown error")
    }
}
```

And this is a specific usecase class:

```
class GetClientConfigUseCase @Inject constructor(private val repository: UserRepository) :
    SingleUseCase<ClientConfigResponse>() {

    override fun buildUseCaseSingle(): Single<ClientConfigResponse> {
        return repository.getUserConfig()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you defined your UseCase class(es)?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I updated my answear with how i defined my class that i use to build the use case, and a generic use case class

Comment: Thanks. I unfortunately barely know any RxJava, but maybe someone else will be able to help you now. I think this would be quite a bit easier with coroutines, but it can be kind of clumsy to mix Rx and coroutines.

Comment: Maybe you could use some counter and decrement it after every request? And after your counter decreases to 0, you can observe it or do some other functionality. Or you can use RxJava zip operator as described in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45454042/11204066

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need zip operation. With zip operation you can have a result of two observable in one place when both of them received data.

```
Observable<List<ClientProducts>> observable1 = ...
Observable<List<DtoTherapy>> observable2 = ...

Observable.zip(observable1, observable2, new BiFunction<List<ClientProducts>, List<DtoTherapy>, Result>() {

    @Override
    public Result apply(List<ClientProducts> products, List<DtoTherapy> therapies) throws Exception
    {
        // here you have both of your data
        // do operations on products and therapies
        // then return the result
        return result;
    }
});
```